# MacBook Pro fan always on

Tags: macbook-pro

I noticed that for the past few days my MacBook Pro has been running the fan non-stop. I dont know if this is a problem, should I be worried? Is this something that I can solve on my own? Should I bring it into the Apple store?

Comment: Are you using any Adobe products for video editing, etc, or are you running your own code? I find that my fan will run on my MBP when I am using processor intensive applications or code that I have written that taxes the CPU and memory. It could be that a process got hung up and is still running. In Spotlight you can run Activity Monitor, and look and see if you have a process that is not responding. If you do you can force quit it and see if your fan slows down.

Answer (score 3):

If it is the same as mine, it was fixed by:

1. Opening **Activity Monitor** and see if any background processes are running.
   If there are, then quit them.
2. If that didn't work, you might need to do a SMC. System Management Controller reset.

#### ***To reset the SMC:***

Shut down the computer.

Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your computer.

On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.

Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.

Press the power button to turn on the computer.

On MagSafe power adapters, the LED might change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

#### To read more about troubleshooting the fan read this: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295

Answer (score 0):

I had my fan always turned on at very high speed, and couldn't find the cause. With some research I found a solution. This might only apply to me, however, I though I share it anyway, just in case.

- In Activity Monitor I realized that the process **launchd** uses up more than 80% of the CPU.
- In Console **system.log** I found these lines repeating every second:

  ```
  (com.google.keystone.system.agent[79014]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent
  ```

In the folder `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`, I simply deleted the file `com.google.keystone.agent.plist`. Problem solved.

Beware! I have no clue whatsoever, what I killed there. I don't like Google to o much. I see no reason what Google wants to update on my machine.